# Localization file for Blazor with multiple .resx per language

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, localization, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I am implementing the localization for a Blazor WebAssembly app. and everything works fine with one .resx file. However, I am wondering if it is possible to use multiple .resx for same language, I tried to look in the documentation but it is somehow not mentioned anywhere, and all tutotial or documentation end-up calling the unique resource with:

`@inject IStringLocalizer<LocalizationRes> _L`

So, is it possible to use multiple .resx for the same language?if yes, how the IStringLocalizer should be used in that case ?

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean one `.resx` file per component/page for a particular language? I don't see a reason why one would need multiple `.resx` files for one language (if we are talking about localizing a particular component/page).

Comment: Hi, No, I am talking about multiple .resx of the same language for a particular language of the full app.

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple Resx files for same language, and distribute them along your project structure. i.e. if you have a folder structure like this

```
MainFolder
..Cats
....Cats.razor.cs
....Cats.razor
Resources
..Cats
....Cats.en.resx <- english resource
....Cats.es.resx <- spanish resource
```

in your injection you should use as following:

> @inject Microsoft.Extensions.Localization.IStringLocalizer
> _localizer

to use you implement as i.e.:

> <TitleComponent Title="@_localizer["Cats"]"
> Description="@_localizer["All your Cats."]" />

in the resx you should provide a translation for each implementation and once you propagate the culture change in your app it will take the correct resx file.

> _localizer["Cats"].

this to support more than one language, to have multiple files of the same language just apply the same structure along your project i.e.

```
MainFolder
..Cats
....Cats.razor.cs
....Cats.razor
..Dogs
....Dogs.razor.cs
....Dogs.razor
Resources
..Cats
....Cats.en.resx <- english resource
....Cats.es.resx <- spanish resource
..Dogs
....Dogs.en.resx
....Dogs.es.resx
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this is not what I am looking for, I am looking to use multiple .resx for the same language for the full app. I am not looking to localize each webpage separately.

Comment: @Raziel : Did you had any luck with finding an answer? I'm running into similar issue with Blazor where I want single global .resx file per language and not per page bases.